# Want to schedule a task in Jenkins to trigger on the first Tuesday of March and September

Tags: jenkins, cron

I would like to schedule a Jenkins task to run on the first Tuesday of March and September sometime in the 3am hour.

I think the trigger should be set to

```
triggers {
    cron('H 3 1-7 3,9 3')
}
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to correct cron expression.
The `day of week` field starts with `0` where `0` corresponds to `SUN`. So the correct code is:

```
triggers {
cron('H 3 1-7 3,9 2')
}
```